# "Humor is one of the strongest forces that humans connect over."?

Tags: grammar, metaphors

English isn't my first language so this question may seem stupid.

Can you connect "over" something metaphorically?

Example: Humor is one of the strongest forces that humans connect over.

Of can you only connect over the internet or some other kind of physical wire?

Comment: How 'bout ***with*** instead?

Comment: @Jim - "with" connotes a connection with humor itself, not the other humans.

Comment: @medica- I suppose in the abstract that's the literal interpretation, but if I was asked how my brother and I keep in touch, and I said, "We keep in touch with our cell phones." People would not interpret that incorrectly. (I hope).

Comment: "Humor is one of the strongest forces for connecting humans" or something like that seems like it would be more straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible to connect "over" something; for example:

> Instead of connecting over a shared desire for three bedrooms and two-and-a-half baths, they connected over their shared desire for community. [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=phTIGIz_mLIC&pg=PR13&dq=connecting+connected)]

However, your specific example doesn't really work; we can view humor as a force that does things (such as connect people), or we can view humor as a substance that people interact with (such as by connecting over it), but we can't view it both ways at once. The result is a *[mixed metaphor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mixed-metaphor)*.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a little awkward to my ears because *force* doesn't quite fit with a connection, but consider this [headline](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/support/explain-wifi-connection-2.html):

> How Does my Android Device **Connect Over** Wifi?

This is a common way to describe a two-way electric or electronic communications pathway.  And it has become a metaphoric way to describe a venue for sharing views and experiences.  If you're ever in Austin, Texas, reach out to the Women Communicators of Austin for their next "Connect Over Cocktails" [event](http://wcaustin.org/wcevents/connect-over-cocktails/).